# How to display flash message after redirect in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to create a logout link which will redirect to login page which is all done i just wanted to know that how can i show some flash message on top of my login section that "you are sucessfully logout"?

{path: 'logout', redirectTo:'/login'}

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this URL:https://github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages.

In your logout(), you can simply use this functionality and can display message.